# При использовании библиотеки locomotive scroll столкнулся с проблемой при которой неправильно вычисляется размер контейнера для скролла

Tags: javascript, html, css, библиотеки

Всем привет. Задача такая: есть контейнер со свойством display flex, flex-direction column. В нем два блока с размерами ~7300px и 14900px. Из-за того, что второй блок с большим размером имеет скорость data-scroll-speed="18", он прокручивается быстрее чем должен, по мнению библиотеки. В моем понимании крипт должен понимать каким размером должен быть родительский блок если скорость дочернего, например, 18, как в моем случае. Я очень надеюсь на какую-нибудь подсказку, как решить эту проблему, буду очень благодарен за любое мнение. Я почти пишу на stackoverflow, поэтому не умею правильно пользоваться вставкой кода, но вот мой код:

```js
function mainLocomotiveScroll() {
  const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    lerp: 0.02
  });
  
}
mainLocomotiveScroll();
```

```css
html.has-scroll-smooth {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html.has-scroll-dragging {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.has-scroll-smooth body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-scroll-smooth [data-scroll-container] {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-container] {
  height: 100vh;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-section] {}

.c-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 11px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.45);
}

.c-scrollbar:hover,
.has-scroll-scrolling .c-scrollbar,
.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar {
  opacity: 1;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.3);
}

.c-scrollbar_thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main-title__img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 265px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-title__img-pic {
  transition: 1.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main__title {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

:root {
  --bgColor: #B24201;
  --fontColor: #DDD0BD;
}
.container{
     height: calc(100dvh - 86px - 67px);       
     overflow-y: unset;
     overflow-x: unset;
     transition: .5s;
    }
  .main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: start;
    height: 360px;
    height: 630px;
    /* width: 3000px; */
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .main__title{
    font-family: "DrukCyr-Bold";
    font-size: 484px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 75%;
    letter-spacing: -4.84px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
  }

  
  
  .description{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    gap:100px;
    list-style-type:none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;  
  }
  
  
  .description__scroll {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 245px;
  
  
  }
  
  .description__scroll-title {
    align-self: end;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
  
  .description__scroll-num {
    align-self: end;
    font-size: 16px;
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 3 / 3;
  }
  
  .description__scroll-text {
    width:455px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  
  .description__button{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: end;
    gap:-1em;
  
  }
  
  .description__button-scroll{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
  
  .description__button-next{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-left: -5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@4.0.6/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js"></script>
<div data-scroll-container data-scroll-section>

  <div class="container">

    <section class="main" style="width: 7355px" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="0.5" data-scroll-position="left">
      <div class="main__title ">
        <span>Smart</span>
        <div class="main-title__img">
          <img class="main-title__img-pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7b/2c/4f/7b2c4f99283903ce89ac40f605a9d2a3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>way</span>
        <div class="main-title__img">
          <img class="main-title__img-pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7b/2c/4f/7b2c4f99283903ce89ac40f605a9d2a3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>of</span>
        <div class="main-title__img">
          <img class="main-title__img-pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7b/2c/4f/7b2c4f99283903ce89ac40f605a9d2a3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>investment</span>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="description-skin" style="width: 7355px" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="18" data-scroll-position="left">

      <ul class="description">

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Философия</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">01</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">Философия нашего бренда основывается на&nbsp;энергии и&nbsp;страсти к&nbsp;созданию великолепных проектов. Мы&nbsp;проявляем расчётливость и&nbsp;гибкость в&nbsp;нашей работе, стремясь превзойти ожидания клиентов. Честность и&nbsp;открытость
            являются основой наших отношений с&nbsp;партнёрами и&nbsp;клиентами.</div>
        </li>

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Экспертиза</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">02</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">В&nbsp;основе нашего подхода лежит глубокое понимание динамичного рынка недвижимости и&nbsp;его потенциала роста. Мы&nbsp;тщательно определяем лучшие инвестиционные возможности и&nbsp;местоположение объектов, используя обширные исследования
            и&nbsp;анализ рынка для обоснования решений.</div>
        </li>

        <!-- <div class="description__button">              
                <div class="description__button-scroll">Scroll</div>
                <div class="description__button-next">Next</div>
              </div> -->

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Ориентиры</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">03</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">Благодаря стратегическому партнёрству с&nbsp;архитекторами, инженерами, дизайнерами и&nbsp;строительными компаниями мы&nbsp;воплощаем в&nbsp;жизнь концептуальные идеи, создавая объекты, отвечающие международным стандартам строительства и&nbsp;выдержавшие
            испытание временем.</div>
        </li>

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Перспективы</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">04</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">Мы&nbsp;уделяем первостепенное внимание экологическому проектированию, энергоэффективности и&nbsp;взаимодействию с&nbsp;населением, стремясь создавать пространства, которые улучшают как окружающую среду, так и&nbsp;качество жизни жителей и&nbsp;окружающих
            их&nbsp;сообществ.</div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Уточню, что библиотека адекватно выполняет свою работу, но когда горизонтальный скролл доходит до конца элементов - он почему-то не заканчивается и примерно столько же скролится в пустом пространстве. Для примера: если я задам фиксированный размер блокам равный 7300px, то контейнер поймет размер и будет скроллиться до этого момента, но это не выход, потому что тогда я лишаюсь гибкости и контейнер не будет подстраиваться под контент. Надеюсь я достаточно понятно расписал...

Comment: для большей наглядности снял видео что именно идет не так. На нем видно что контент заканчивается раньше чем скролл. Гораздо раньше.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/21505674?key=0e283f2601b222d23cbfbb2b0caa8d21